Help with my bachelor's thesis
My bachelor's thesis is a research one. I am solving a specific problem using my ideas, combined with an existing approach, method, and the results are original. My supervisor doesn't know what to say or how to interpret the results. I have received a feedback from other professors saying that my contributions should be specified clearly and that the conclusions aren't presented in an academic manner. I have used "we" in the whole thesis and it would be weird to say "this chapter is original except for one part..". Also, I think I should somehow interpret my conclusions. Should I have a section named conclusions? How should I phrase that my work is original without it sounding like bragging?

Hi! What is your actual question to us? Currently, we cannot help you with what you've asked here.

If you write a thesis, then you are trying to communicate with your supervisor. That does not seem to work right now. So you need to sit down with your supervisor and together figure out how to fix that.

Thank you for your replies.

How do you know you are solving the problem if not even your supervisor knows how to interpret the results? It seems like all the feedback you are receiving points to a communication problem - your supervisor does not understand what you present to them, and the professors are not clear on what you present to them either. Most likely the use of "we" and lack/existence of a conclusion isn't the root of the problem.

@MisterMiyagi I checked it with a program on the computer and the solution is correct. You're right, the problem is communication. I probably do not express myself clearly. My ideas are logical, they haven't said I'm wrong, but I think it's in the way they're organised.

One big aspect of learning to do research is learning to communicate your results so that they are clear, at least to your intended audience. In my experience,, this is usually more of a task for grad students, but writing an undergraduate thesis is good practice. Can your supervisor say what is unclear? Can you get a friend or classmate to read it and suggest things?  If you get your supervisor's OK, you might want to send it to an academic editor, although they would probably charge you something.

@PeterFlom thank you. Yes, my friends say it sounds clear to them. They gave me some suggestions. But they don't know the appropriate format either for this type of problems. What is an academic editor? Thank you for your response.

@Student most schools in the US and Canada have some kind of (free of charge) writing support specialist for specifically this purpose. Have you sought out such services at your institution? My suggestion would be to first sit down with your advisor and figure out what exactly they think you need to do (and write down what they tell you!)--this is part of their responsibility as an advisor--and then go see a writing specialist to work on improving your draft.

@principles-investigator thank you. Well, my coordinator doesn't understand the basics of the subject and isn't willing to understand them. Sadly, my university doesn't offer such services. Thank you for your response.

A supervisor should be an en expert in the field of your research. I don't understand, is nobody available to supervise your research in your department? That seems quite odd.
